# xslt transformation - match a value and show as result only this part of the xml

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have a question to a transformation. I would just have as result all Gates which are active (active='true') and all gates which are false I want have in my result.

This is a part of my XML:

```
<Plant>
        <PlantName>12</PlantName>
        <Gate name="12" active="false" AlwaysOn="true">
```

Here is my xslt:

```
    <xsl:template match="text()" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:for-each select="//Plant">
                <Plant>
                    <PlantName>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PlantName"></xsl:value-of>
                    </PlantName>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Gate">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="../Name"></xsl:copy-of>
                        <xsl:if match="../../Gate[@active='true']">
                            <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Plant>
            </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At my result I get all gates (also which are active='false'). Can someone tell what is wrong here, please :)

Thanks in advance.

BRs
Hartman

Comment: Are you sure that's really your XSLT code?  The `xsl:if` element doesn't accept a `match` attribtue.

Comment: Oh, right. It should be test attribute. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<xsl:if test="@active='true'">
```

Comment: If that was the right answer, are you going to mark it as such :)